# How old was Teclis at the End of Times?

Tags: warhammer-fantasy

I'm sticking with Teclis because (as far as I know) he was never resurrected. Which makes things easier than for Tryion!

Teclis rose to fame during the dark elf incursion, after which he traveled to the Empire and founded the colleges of magic (which presumably was a while ago from the Empire's perspective).

Elves have extended lifespans with some living thousands of years but is there enough information given to tell us exactly how old Teclis was when he

> died

During the End of Times?

Comment: Isn't that spoiler unnecessary when you mention in the first sentence that *"he was never resurrected"*?

Comment: @Wikis you don't have to die to be not resurrected (his twin was at least once), you may just never have needed it - but yes, probably even more so now it's been two years since the books came out!